# How to redirect Python Syntax Error into a textbox in MFC or other GUI framwork?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I embed Python into my GUI application, when the script throws syntax errors, I want to redirect the error message into a textbox, so I can know where the error is.

My codes is very simple:

```
Py_Initialize()
PyRun_SimpleString( "execfile('my.py')" );
Py_Finalize();
```

If the file contains syntax error, it may looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "my.py", line 3, in <module>
    app=everedit.Ap
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ap'
```

The above messages can be seen in a console window, but now I want to cache these messages in a GUI window.
A GUI window don't have a console. I want to output such messages into a text box.

Please note that I embed Python into C++, I want to cache Python's Syntax Error in C++.

Comment: Show us what you tried. And explain what you're actually trying to do. `PyParse_SimpleParseString` is just going to parse the code, without running, or even compiling, anything. Is that really what you want? If so, it will return you a `struct _node *` for the head of the parse tree on success, or NULL on failure. Did you fail to write a check for NULL?

Comment: Also, you really want only `SyntaxError`? If the script throws some other unhandled exception, what do you want to do about that?

Comment: My codes is very simple:

Py_Initialize()
PyRun_SimpleString( "execfile('my.py')" );
Py_Finalize();

If the file contains syntax error, it may looks like:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "my.py", line 3, in <module>
    app=everedit.Ap
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ap'

The above messages can be seen in a console window, but now I want to cache these messages in a GUI window.
A GUI window don't have a console. I want to output such messages into a text box.

Comment: Edit the question to include that information; don't leave a vague and unanswerable question that tricks people into wasting their time leaving irrelevant answers, and then try to explain more in comments.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `PyRun_SimpleString` to run an `execfile` call? Why not run the file directly (e.g., with `PyRun_File`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for [`PyRun_SimpleString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags) clearly says:

> Returns 0 on success or -1 if an exception was raised. **If there was an error, there is no way to get the exception information.**

So, if you want to get the exception information, you have to use slightly lower-level functions.

Meanwhile, once you're using the right function, and it returns `NULL` or `-1` to tell you an exception occurred, how do you get the exception information (and distinguish `SyntaxError` from other exceptions, for whatever reason you want to do that)?

There's a whole chapter in the C-API docs on [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html). But briefly: You call `PyErr_Occurred` to get the type of the exception. Then you call `PyErr_ExceptionMatches` to check whether it's the type you want. If so, use `PyErr_Fetch` to get the value and traceback so you can format them yourself, or `PyErr_Format` to get a simple formatted string, or whatever else you want. Then you just extract the Unicode or ASCII bytes from the string and put them in your GUI window.

Comment: Thanks for you guidance, now I know what should I do.

Answer (score -1):

Use a try/catch block and the `traceback` module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)).

```
import traceback

try:
    PyParser_SimpleParseString(input())
except SyntaxError as e:
    # There will always be one line, but we're better off still looping over the list
    # To be extra safe!
    for line in traceback.format_exception_only(e.__class__, str(e)):
        print(line) # Replace this with what write to the GUI
```

This will only give you the `SyntaxError: x` part, if you also want the traceback, use [`traceback.format_exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception).

Comment: Thanks. PyParser_SimpleParseString is a C API of python, can I use the above codes? It throws errors: NameError: name 'PyParser_SimpleParseString' is not defined